# jQuery .on('click') doesn't work on first click but the second

Tags: jquery

I have 6 tabs and only one has class active. When I click any other, clicked tab gets active class. I have a task to get value from selected tab, the one which gets active class after being clicked. The problem is that my `.on('click')` method shows me tab with active class only after I clicked that tab second time. Here is my code:

```js
$('div[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        var activeTemplateID = $('.active-template-id.text-danger').data('template-id');
        console.log(activeTemplateID);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="2" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" 
      role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" 
      aria-selected="true" 
      class="align-items-end nav-item nav-link  letter pl-0 pr-0 nav-home-tab" 
      style="display: grid;">
 </div>
```

I want to get selected tab's class after I click on it first time. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like this binding is potentially being made before the binding that swaps the active class.  If so, it's an ordering issue.

Comment: Forgot to add html in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put if condition.

It should work without if condition! because click is already making tab active! you can take it's data in normal way!

```
$('div[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(){
   setTimeout(function(){  
        var activeTemplateID = $('.active-template-id.text-danger').data('template-id');
        console.log(activeTemplateID); 
    }, 500);


})

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the order of bindings to fix the issue, then I would suggest changing your binding to be a delegate instead.

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'div[data-toggle="tab"]', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        var activeTemplateID = $('.active-template-id.text-danger').data('template-id');
        console.log(activeTemplateID);
    }
});
```

Changing the binding should let the direct bindings on the element be processed first, which should adjust the active class.  Then once the event has bubbled up to the body element, it will process your logic.